# Merging the 2 dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe df1 and df2 and I want to merge both of them such that I don't loose any entry of df1 and common columns in both the dataframes are

```
df1 = r_date, symbol 
df2 = date, symbol
```

I want to merge the dataframes such that I don't loose any entry in df1.

I tried using the following

```
merged_left = pd.merge(left=df1,  right=df2, how='inner', left_on=['symbol','r_date'], right_on=['symbol','date'])
merged_left
```

But the problem is that it is dropping entries from df1. Can anyone advise a way to do the same.

There are total 3442 rows in df1 and almost 2,000,000 entries in df2. What I am looking at is to add that if symbol and r_date are not matching in the df2, add the columns from df2 as NA

Can anyone help

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `how=left` instead of `inner`, like this:

**Since you want all records from `df1` , you need to make it as left dataframe and use `how=left`**, where `left` is like `LEFT JOIN`.

```
merged_left = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left', left_on=['symbol','r_date'], right_on=['symbol','date'])
```